# Reading dates in different formats from a file and sorting them

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, date, dataframe

<sub>This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46064162/extracting-and-sorting-dates-in-different-formats-from-a-file-using-pandas/46064313?noredirect=1#comment79099220_46064313) one and I originally answered it with this solution but it turns out I misread the question. However, I feel my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46069435/4909087) would be useful for a slightly different use case, and so I post it here.</sub>

---

Given a text file:

```
04/20/2009; 04/20/09; 4/20/09; 4/3/09
Mar-20-2009; Mar 20, 2009; March 20, 2009; Mar. 20, 2009; Mar 20 2009;
20 Mar 2009; 20 March 2009; 20 Mar. 2009; 20 March, 2009
Mar 20th, 2009; Mar 21st, 2009; Mar 22nd, 2009
Feb 2009; Sep 2009; Oct 2010
6/2008; 12/2009
2009; 2010
```

Containing already extracted dates in varying formats... the task is to read them into a data frame and then sort them, and then display the output in MM/DD/YYYY format.

Expected output:

```
0     06/01/2008
1     01/01/2009
2     02/01/2009
3     03/20/2009
4     03/20/2009
5     03/20/2009
6     03/20/2009
7     03/20/2009
8     03/20/2009
9     03/20/2009
10    03/20/2009
11    03/20/2009
12    03/20/2009
13    03/21/2009
14    03/22/2009
15    04/03/2009
16    04/20/2009
17    04/20/2009
18    04/20/2009
19    09/01/2009
20    12/01/2009
21    01/01/2010
22    10/01/2010
```

How can this be done in pandas?

Note: If the day is missing, consider the 1st and if the month is missing consider January.

Comment: I have seen this somewhere.

Comment: @Bharathshetty yes. check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46064162/extracting-and-sorting-dates-in-different-formats-from-a-file-using-pandas/46064313?noredirect=1#comment79099220_46064313). But the OP wanted something different.

Comment: Not that one. Maybe a coursera assignment I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplier should be omit `apply` and `reset_index` only once:

In my opinion `drop=1` is worse readable like `drop=True`.

```
out = pd.to_datetime(df.stack()).sort_values().dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y').reset_index(drop=True)
print(out)
0     06/01/2008
1     01/01/2009
2     02/01/2009
3     03/20/2009
4     03/20/2009
5     03/20/2009
6     03/20/2009
7     03/20/2009
8     03/20/2009
9     03/20/2009
10    03/20/2009
11    03/20/2009
12    03/20/2009
13    03/21/2009
14    03/22/2009
15    04/03/2009
16    04/20/2009
17    04/20/2009
18    04/20/2009
19    09/01/2009
20    12/01/2009
21    01/01/2010
22    10/01/2010
dtype: object
```

Comment: Nice... you removed the apply.

Comment: I think you want `df.apply(pd.to_datetime).stack()` - then `apply` is necessary. Maybe it was origin idea.

Answer (score 2):

Reproducible setup (for an easy MCVE):

```
import pandas as pd
import io

text = '''04/20/2009; 04/20/09; 4/20/09; 4/3/09
Mar-20-2009; Mar 20, 2009; March 20, 2009; Mar. 20, 2009; Mar 20 2009;
20 Mar 2009; 20 March 2009; 20 Mar. 2009; 20 March, 2009
Mar 20th, 2009; Mar 21st, 2009; Mar 22nd, 2009
Feb 2009; Sep 2009; Oct 2010
6/2008; 12/2009
2009; 2010'''

buf = io.stringIO(text)

df = pd.read_csv(buf, engine='python', delimiter=';\s+', header=None).reset_index()

df

            index               0               1               2  \
0      04/20/2009        04/20/09         4/20/09          4/3/09   
1     Mar-20-2009    Mar 20, 2009  March 20, 2009   Mar. 20, 2009   
2     20 Mar 2009   20 March 2009    20 Mar. 2009  20 March, 2009   
3  Mar 20th, 2009  Mar 21st, 2009  Mar 22nd, 2009            None   
4        Feb 2009        Sep 2009        Oct 2010            None   
5          6/2008         12/2009            None            None   
6            2009            2010            None            None   

              3  
0          None  
1  Mar 20 2009;  
2          None  
3          None  
4          None  
5          None  
6          None
```

Replace `buf` with the name of your text file.

---

You can use `df.apply` and `df.stack`, followed by `pd.Series.sort_values`.

```
out = df.stack().apply(pd.to_datetime)\
        .reset_index(drop=1)\
        .sort_values().dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')\
        .reset_index(drop=1)
print(out)

0     06/01/2008
1     01/01/2009
2     02/01/2009
3     03/20/2009
4     03/20/2009
5     03/20/2009
6     03/20/2009
7     03/20/2009
8     03/20/2009
9     03/20/2009
10    03/20/2009
11    03/20/2009
12    03/20/2009
13    03/21/2009
14    03/22/2009
15    04/03/2009
16    04/20/2009
17    04/20/2009
18    04/20/2009
19    09/01/2009
20    12/01/2009
21    01/01/2010
22    10/01/2010
```