# pandas - convert a column with multiple date formats to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, string-to-datetime

I have a column in a dataframe with multiple date formats that need to be converted to datetime.

```
date              amount
September 2018    15
Sep-18            20
```

The output should look like

```
date              amount
2018-09-01        15
2018-09-01        20
```

Using pd.to_datetime(df['Month']) returns the error...

OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-09-18 00:00:00

Comment: why sep 2018 return 2017 ?

Comment: sorry, that was a typo

Comment: and why sep-18 is not 2018-09-18 since for me this is make more sense .

Comment: Sep-18 is in the format Mmm-YY, so needs to be converted to a month and year date format

Comment: [Extracting dates that are in different formats using regex and sorting them - pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46064162/extracting-dates-that-are-in-different-formats-using-regex-and-sorting-them-pa/) This might help. But needs a bit of alteration.

Comment: One easy solution is to write your own date parsing function for the data you have and use `df['date'].map(yourfunction)`on the dataframe.Check `df['date'].unique()` to see the date formats.